# Not Supported Exception while Binding

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to bind 2 strings from FileSystemWatcher (Name, FullPath) if a file is created.

I'm using a ObservableCollection and maybe I'm using it wrong.

This is what I've tried

```
private void StartFileMonitor()
    {
        var _monitorFolders = new List<string> {
            Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData).Replace("Roaming", string.Empty),
            Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
        };

        try {

            foreach (var folder in _monitorFolders) {

                // Check if Folder Exists
                if (Directory.Exists(folder)) {

                    FileSystemWatcher _fileSysWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

                    _fileSysWatcher.Path = folder;
                    _fileSysWatcher.Filter = "*.*";

                    // Created
                    _fileSysWatcher.Created += (sender, e) => {

                        _fileMonitorEntries.Add(new FileMonitor {
                            FileName = e.Name,     // Here is the Exception 
                            FilePath = e.FullPath  //
                        });
                    };

                    // Deleted
                    _fileSysWatcher.Deleted += (sender, e) => {

                        _fileMonitorEntries.Add(new FileMonitor {
                            FileName = e.Name,
                            FilePath = e.FullPath
                        });
                    };

                  _fileSysWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                }
            }

            lstFileMonitorEntries.ItemsSource = _fileMonitorEntries;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Here's the XML Code

```
            <ListBox Name="lstFileMonitorEntries" Height="358" Canvas.Left="292" Canvas.Top="10" Width="482" Background="#FF252222">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FileName}" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Segeo WP Light" Foreground="White"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FilePath}" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Segeo WP Light" Foreground="Red" />

                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Does anybody have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How is your binding declared?

Comment: You do realize that you're potentialaly adding the same files to a collection twice ?

Comment: Do you mean the 2 event handlers and the properties?

Comment: Yes, your adding a new `FileMonitor` when you create and delete, that could potentially be the same file.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice fixed it, but the main issue remains any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing `thread affinity issue` here. `ObservableCollection` binded to UI element `cannot be modified from other than UI thread`.

And `Created` and `Deleted` event are `called on background thread` and hence any update in collection is not allowed from that thread.

You need to `delegate them on UI dispatcher` so that it gets `execute on UI thread`. UI dispatcher can be accessed using `App.Current.Dispatcher` This is how it can be done -

```
_fileSysWatcher.Created += (sender, e) =>
      {
          App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
          {
              _fileMonitorEntries.Add(new FileMonitor
              {
                 FileName = e.Name,
                 FilePath = e.FullPath
              });
          });
      };
```

Similarly delegate the code in delete event on UI dispatcher as well.